# Getting NULL / empty data when running fetch(URL) with useEffect() in React client

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, use-effect

I have built a NodeJS server that reliably supports an API

```
http://localhost:5000/record/gopa
```

that returns a well formed JSON string

```
{"pid":
  {
   "ck":"F1965121910:265.522.5788.37",
   "name":"gopa",
   "cID":"MVOE9BW5ZZOC"
   }
}
```

I have built a ReactJS client to received this JSON output and convert it into a string for subsequent processing as follows:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
 
export default function Detail52() {
 const params = useParams();
 const [dbdata, setData] = useState('empty52');
 
 useEffect(() => {
   async function getData() {
   //const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/record/${params.id.toString()}`);
   const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/record/gopa}`);
 
     if (!response.ok) {
       const message = `An error occurred: ${response.statusText}`;
       window.alert(message);
       return;
     }
     
     const dbdata = await response.json();
     window.alert(JSON.stringify(dbdata));
     setData(dbdata);
     //setData('fake data')
   }
   getData();
   return;
 },[dbdata]);
 
 return (
   <div>
     <h3>Detail 52</h3>     
       <p>{dbdata}</p>
       <p>{JSON.stringify(dbdata)}</p>
   </div>
 );
 
}
```

When this executes, I get NULL value in ***dbdata*** and a empty string when I convert the JSON output into a string. 
I was initially under the impression that the ***${params.id.toString()}*** was not being passed correctly, so for the time being I have hardcoded the parameter and the effect is the same. 
I have tested this by placing an alert after ***dbdata*** is fetched and it shows ***null*** 
To complete the testing, I have also placed a 'fake data' using the ***setData()*** functions and this fake data is correctly reflected in the final output. 
So, I think, the problem is not with the ***setData()*** but with an empty string being returned.
I have been struggling with this for quite some time and I think that I have localised the problem. Would be very grateful if someone can help me sort this out.

Comment: Make sure cors is working properly. I would suggest using a .catch after .json and see if anything comes up.

Comment: Make sure you have the right url in your `fetch` function

Comment: Please have a look at your networking tab and check the requested URL and the server response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you inserted the wrong URL since you have a bracket at the end of it:

```
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/record/gopa}`);
//Instead of
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/record/gopa`);
```

I saw that you are awaiting **twice** your object:

- The first after the fetch:

```
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/record/gopa}`);
```

- The second (that seems unnecessary):

```
const dbdata = await response.json();
// How it should be:
const dbdata = response.json();
```

Can you please log us the content of the response, to understand if this is the issue or if the problem comes from another part of your code? I will edit the post if that's the case

Comment: Yes, the } at the end of the URL was the culprit. Removing it, gets me the data. Thanks a ton. Also, using the parameter is ALSO working. However, your second advice to replace the second await and do a direct assignment is causing a problem and the data is getting washed out again. So I am retaining. Anyway, my main problem is resolved. Thanks a lot for that quick reply.